# jQuery can't find proper selector

Tags: jquery, selector

I'm using jQuery to append (move) a `div` into another `div`. This is working fine, but now I'm trying to make it a function and I'm running into some problems.

I have a few `div`'s, two called `#geregeld` and `#niet_geregeld`. One called `#content_vragen` and a `class` called `.container_vragen`.

The `.container_vragen` is initally placed in the `#content_vragen`. In the `.container_vragen` is a button with this code:

```
 $('.submenu').on('click','.groen',function() {
            $(this).closest('.container_vragen').fadeOut(400, function() {
                $(this).closest('.container_vragen').css({overflow : 'hidden', color : 'green'});
                $(this).closest('.container_vragen').appendTo("#geregeld");
                $(this).closest('.container_vragen').fadeIn(400);
            });
        });
```

This action puts the `.container_vragen` in the `#geregeld` `div`. This works fine. But I want the user to be able to put the `.container_vragen` back into the `#content_vragen` `div` and this is proving to be a problem.

The code I'm using to do that is this:

```
function appendToContent_vragen() {
        $(this).closest('.container_vragen').fadeOut(400, function() {
            $(this).closest('.container_vragen').appendTo('#content_vragen');
            $(this).closest('.container_vragen').css({overflow : 'hidden', color : 'black'});
            $(this).closest('.container_vragen').fadeIn(400);
        });
    }
```

This also works. The problem is selecting the right div in the #geregeld div.

```
$('#geregeld , #niet_geregeld').on('click',function(){
        $('.container_vragen', this).click(appendToContent_vragen);
    });
```

If I use this code I have to click twice on the `.container_vragen` in `#geregeld` to get to the function `appendToContent_vragen` and obviously I want the user to click only once.

I have small jsFiddle with the code I'm using: http://jsfiddle.net/hE7Gm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting confused by all the Dutch, but in this block:

```
$('#geregeld , #niet_geregeld').on('click',function(){
    $('.container_vragen', this).click(appendToContent_vragen);
});
```

you maybe have two problems.  The first is that the inner call to `.click` does not make a click, but is *registering* a new click handler, just like `.on('click', ...)` does.  I can't tell if that's a real problem or not because I can't tell what the site is really supposed to do.

The second problem is setting `this` when `appendToContent_vragen` is called.  If, as I suspect, you just want to call that function immediately (without a second click)

```
$('#geregeld, #niet_geregeld').on('click', function() {
     $('.container_vragen', this).each(appendToContent_vragen);
});
```

This works because `.each` will call the supplied function with `this` equal to the current element.

Also, in your animation functions there's no need for all those `.closest()` calls - you already know that the passed element is a `.container_vragen`, so:

```
function appendToContent_vragen() {
    $(this).fadeOut(400, function() {
        $(this).appendTo('#content_vragen')
               .css({overflow : 'hidden', color : 'black'})
               .fadeIn(400);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the respons. This pretty much does what I want it too. But sometimes I have multiple `.container_vragen` in  `#geregeld`. When I click the `.container_vragen` in `#geregeld` and there are two or more `.container_vragen` they all call the function `appendToContent_vragen` because of the each selector. Is there a way to only have the `.container_vragen` that is being clicked call the function?

Comment: @PeterBoomsma you would need to register the handlers directly on the `.container_vragen` elements, not the two container elements.